# Multiple docker networks on a single container

Tags: docker, docker-network, docker-stack

I have a docker stack configuration with an overlay network called `traefik`. It contains my `traefik` reverse-proxy container and then several containers that serve various subdomains. I'm adding a new one that'll need to access a database server that I've created in another container, so I added something like this:

```
networks:
  traefik:
    driver: overlay
  database:
    driver: overlay

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    networks:
      - traefik
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      # ...

  # ...

  database:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine # match what's being used by heroku
    networks:
      - database

  staging:
    image: staging
    networks:
      - traefik
      - database
deploy:
  labels:
    traefik.enable: "true"
    traefik.frontend.rule: Host:lotto-ticket.example.com
    traefik.docker.network: traefik
    traefik.port: 3000
```

When I did this, the reverse proxy started returning Gateway Timeout codes, indicating that the `staging` container was no longer available to the `traefik` network. If I remove the `database` network from the `staging` container, the subdomain serves up as expected (although it obviously fails to access the database), and when I add it back in, the reverse-proxy starts getting timeouts from it.

Is there some kind of conflict between the two networks? Do I need to configure IP routing in order to use multiple docker networks on a single container?

EDIT: added more detail to the config excerpt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell traefik on which network to connect to your service using the label `traefik.docker.network`. In your case, that label would be set to `${stack_name}_traefik` where `${stack_name}` is the name of your stack.

Comment: I was leaving that out, but I do have that label in the configuration (I added some more detail to the original question). However, I was just using `traefik` as the network name and not including the stack name. Changing that fixed it! But do you have any idea why it was working before I attached the second network? Was it defaulting to the host network?

Comment: @xanderflood the network field handles situations when a container has more than one IP address and traefik needs to pick between the two. With only a single IP, traefik doesn't need this field.

Comment: That said, if you publish a port, the container will get added to the ingress network by docker, so it's a good idea to specify it for edge cases where you unexpectedly have more than one network.